# update state of child component from parent component using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

This is how my RespMessages component looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Message } from "semantic-ui-react";


function RespMessages() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("This is a success message");

  return (
    <Message positive>
      <Message.Header>{message}</Message.Header>
    </Message>
  );
}

export default RespMessages;
```

This is how I am using RespMessages component inside a different component.

```
function CreateChannel() {
return (
    <Container>
      <RespMessages />
    </Container>

}
```

This works fine and I can see `This is a success message` when the page renders.

What I am not able to figure out is how do I call `setMessage` of `RespMessages` component from `CreateChannel` component.

Can you please help?

> P.S.: I am react newbie so jargons of react are probably off.

Comment: lift (move) the state up out from `RespMessages` and put them in `CreateChannel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react if you want something to change in the `Child` component depending on the `Parent` component you have to lift the state up to the parent component. If you want to differentiate between what should be state and what should be props and where should the state reside then its simple to figure out.

**State:** Keep the state (`message`) in the component where the data will change. In this case `CreateChannel` component.

**Props:** The components that are dependent on that state (`message`) should get the state as Props. In this case `RespMessages` component.

**setState Methods:** Now in case the child also wants to be able to set the state (`message`) then you can also pass the `setMessage` down as prop from `CreateChannel` to RespMessages`.

The [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) have a very good explanation for all this stuff. Please check it out if needed.

**RespMessages.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Message } from "semantic-ui-react";


function RespMessages({message}) {
  return (
    <Message positive>
      <Message.Header>{message}</Message.Header>
    </Message>
  );
}

export default RespMessages;
```

**CreateChannel.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Container } from "semantic-ui-react"

function CreateChannel() {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
    return (
        <Container>
            <RespMessages message={message} />
        </Container>
    )
}

export default CreateChannel
```

Comment: For people who down vote the answer, it would be helpful if you provide proper feedback as to what the problem was so that I can grow and improve my future answers here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle). Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-fire-fvtvb).

```
let RespMessages = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("This is a success message");
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    setMessage: (msg) => setMessage(msg)
  }));

  return <div>{message}</div>;
});

function App() {
  // In order to gain access to the child component instance,
  // you need to assign it to a `ref`, so we call `useRef()` to get one
  const childRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <RespMessages ref={childRef} />
      <button onClick={() => childRef.current.setMessage('hey')}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

As stated in the docs, this approach should be rarely used. Also consider approaches in other answers.

Comment: According to react docs: `As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases.` Using imperative handle in a simple scenario like this adds unnecessary complexity and may result in difficulty for beginners. I would recommend suggesting good code practices to beginners in such cases

Comment: @HussainNawazLalee Yet, it is there for a reason. So it is better to show someone that such possibility exists, then saying that there doesn't!

Comment: @giogrim I agree with you that showing the possibility is a good thing. But the drawbacks should also be shown and better alternatives as well.

Comment: @HussainNawazLalee The docs in the link I gave already say it should be used rarely, so its OPs responsibility to read further on.

Comment: How do I pass the message from `CreateChannel` instead of hard-coded `Hey` in the `RespMessages` component?

Comment: @Asdfg just replace "Hey" with `message` variable

Answer (score 0):

You don't. A parent company generally should not know about the implementation of a child.

You can move your messages state into parent and pass the messages to child as props. This will change your RespMessage component from being an uncontrolled component, to a controlled component.